# Phalcon - Asset Management - The collection does not exist in the manager

Tags: php, phalcon

In my website i have some pages with jquery lightbox and some pages without lightbox, to load the packages i use following in my controller function which loads the package and assign that to the placeholder.

```
public function loadJSLightbox2()
{
    $this->assets
        ->collection('lightboxJs')
        //->setPrefix($this->config->site->cloud_url)
        ->addJs('web/dist/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js');
    $this->assets
        ->collection('lightboxCss')
        //->setPrefix($this->config->site->cloud_url)
        ->addCss('web/dist/lightbox2/dist/lightbox.min.css');
}
```

However in my volt main template (master template) i have define the place holders like below,

```
 {{ assets.outputJs('lightboxJs') }}
 {{ assets.outputCss('lightboxCss') }}
```

this works fine as long we this loadJSlightbox2 functions is called when loading the page. In pages where i dont need to load the plugin (where these two asset are empty) i get error called as below.

**Phalcon\Assets\Exception: The collection does not exist in the manager**

How do i archive this optional plugin behavior in with phalcon asset management tools in my web application ?

Comment: The syntax is right, looks like the loadJSLightbox2 function is not called properly. Where and when do you call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using following code,

```
{% for key, collection in assets.getCollections() %}
    {% if key == 'origin' %}
        {{ assets.outputJs('origin') }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if key == 'lightboxJs' %}
        {{ assets.outputJs('lightboxJs') }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if key =='colorboxJs' %}
        {{ assets.outputJs('colorboxJs') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are correct. Deleting my answer below to not misguide others.